# Using devenv.exe from the command line and open a Solution

Tags: x86, visual-studio-2017, vsix, devenv, anycpu

I've configured my VSIX-Project to run devenv.exe when I press F5.
This opens the start page from Visual Studio. In order to test my extension I have to manually open a specific solution.

I tried to run devenv with the argument '/Run PathToSolution.sln' this starts VS with the specified Solution but also runs the startup project.
Is there a way to run devenv and open a specific solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`devenv.exe` accepts a solution as an argument. This means that `devenv.exe path\to\your\solution.sln` will have the effect that you're looking for.

Adding /Run tells it to load the solution and run it, if you omit it then it will just load the project. For more information, see [Devenv Command Line Switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches) on Microsoft's official documentation.